# Access to only few fields of a content type for specific user

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have created one content type 'video' in which I have many fields like url,language,locations etc. I have created 1 role, Now I just want to give permissions to that particular role so that he can only add fields like url,locations. He shouldn't be able to use other fields.

I am using drupal 6.

Please help if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /admin/build/modules, CCK portion, and enable the Content Permissions module.  This will allow you to restrict "field-level permissions for CCK fields".

After that, go in and go to /admin/user/permissions.  Grant access to "Create Video Content" in the "node module" section.  Then, scroll up to the content_permissions module, and check the "Edit field_NAME_OF_FIELD" to grant access.  If you don't check, it should show up.

All of the checks should be applied to the role for which you created.

Comment: Even I have also tried the same thing. But Once I give the permission in node module like"create video content", Then it is accessible for all the fields on node/add/video url.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please check it as "answer".  Thanks! :)